# Showing arrowheads in line end using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, symbology

I would like to show arrowheads in the endings of every drawn linestring. 
Is it possible in QGIS?

[image]

I have been trying to use a marker line but repeats all de arroheads all over the line, it is not restricted to the ends:

[image]

Comment: Have a look at https://anitagraser.com/2010/12/15/advanced-layer-styles-in-qgis/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**For 2.16 and up**
See [@nagib 's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/215842/115).

**Before 2.16**
As pointed out by @underdark, you have to use a marker for the end line with a rotation of 90° if you use a triangle. For the start line you need to add another marker, this one rotated 270°:
[image]

If you do not want your arrows to point further than the end of the line, you can add an offset.

Answer (score 14):

QGIS 2.16. version has the option to make the arrows, like this.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could I have an arrowhead only at the end of a polyline? I can only find the checkbox „Repeat arrow on each segment“. When I turn it off, the arrow goes from the first point on the line to the last, ignoring the course of the line.

Comment: The line must be polyline, then select Head type, single or single reversed

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [Arrows plugin](https://bitbucket.org/gpiffault/qgis-plugins/wiki/Arrows) which produces arrows like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit late but in QGIS 3.10 you can  multiple symbols for the same layer. Simply click the plus arrow (underlined in red below)
[image]
However to get the offset you will need to go to the option below.
[image]

Comment: this is a good answer. See also: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/272536/94928