# Adding symbols to the end of a line

Tags: qgis, symbology

Is there a simple way to add symbols (circles, triangles etc) to the end of a line in QGIS?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need it only for display:

(1) Open `Layer Properties | Style`

(2) Click on green <kbd>+</kbd> button two times. Change each `Symbol layer type` to `Marker line` and check `on first vertex only` and `on last vertex only`.

[image]

(3) Default markers would be circles. To change them to triangles, scroll this window  a little down to icon list and select your preferred one.

[image]