# Showing arrowheads at the midpoint of a line with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, symbology

This is related to the question [Showing arrowheads in line end using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/215830)

But I wanted to show the arrow head at the mid-point of a line. This is because the arrow heads can be quite crowded when they meet, e.g. at a common junction (as shown below).

[image]

My question is:

*Is there a way to show the arrow head at the midpoint of a line (in general a certain percentage of length in linear referencing)?*

(This is with QGIS 3.2.0-Bonn)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can workaround by using a marker line with a triangle marker:

[image: screenshot of QGIS 3.2 symbology]

1. Add a Simple line
2. Add a Marker line
3. In "Marker" choose "triangle2"
4. In "Marker line > Marker Placement" either choose:

[image: screenshot of marker placement options in QGIS 3.2]

#### For Midpoint

Choose "on central point"

#### For percentage of length

choose "on first vertex only". Next to "Offset along line" switch to "Map units" and then choose "Edit..." in the corresponding context menu.

[image: Edit... highlighted in context menu of offset along line]

In the Expression String Builder type `$length * 0.2` and then press "Ok". Replace "0.2" by the desired percentage.

[image: $length * 0.2 in expression string builder]

This is the result:

[image: Marker at 20% of line length]