# QGIS: one way streets representation

Tags: qgis, symbology, streets, traffic

How to manage the symbols of the one way street a representation?

I have a field where each link is classified by one way o bidirectional.

I would like that each link read this value to insert an arrow indicating the direction of travel

My field type has this value: bidirectional - north - south - west - east (depending on the prevailing direction)

**Update:** I can also set a boleaan(real 0/1) field to manage the two directions, but I need to show a symbol in the middle of the link that read the orientation (0°/180° or +/-90°) from this field

In the image below a Googlemaps image with the arrows that show the direction of travel:
[image: one_way_links]

Comment: Please provide example data and an example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Do you have a point or line layer?

Comment: I export data from OSM, so the street network is a line type

Comment: See this post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/288106/showing-arrowheads-at-the-midpoint-of-a-line-with-qgis/288109

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this video show the result you want?

[image]

If yes, use this style (save the code at the end of this answer in a text file and change it to the `.qml` format, then apply it to the line layer). [How to apply style?](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#load-style)

The style has a built-in option that allows you to turn the direction of the arrow depending on the value of the boolean field `inversed_direction` (`False` - don't inverse, `True` - inverse direction).

[image]

**Style for line layer (save to .qml format):**

```xml
<!DOCTYPE qgis PUBLIC 'http://mrcc.com/qgis.dtd' 'SYSTEM'>
<qgis version="3.20.3-Odense" styleCategories="Symbology">
  <renderer-v2 type="singleSymbol" symbollevels="1" forceraster="0" enableorderby="0">
    <symbols>
      <symbol type="line" name="0" clip_to_extent="1" renderer_should_use_levels="1" alpha="1" force_rhr="0">
        <data_defined_properties>
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option type="QString" name="name" value=""/>
            <Option name="properties"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="type" value="collection"/>
          </Option>
        </data_defined_properties>
        <layer enabled="1" locked="1" class="SimpleLine" pass="0">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option type="QString" name="align_dash_pattern" value="0"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="capstyle" value="flat"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="customdash" value="5;2"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="customdash_map_unit_scale" value="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="customdash_unit" value="MM"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="dash_pattern_offset" value="0"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="dash_pattern_offset_map_unit_scale" value="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="dash_pattern_offset_unit" value="MM"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="draw_inside_polygon" value="0"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="joinstyle" value="round"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="line_color" value="0,0,0,255"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="line_style" value="solid"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="line_width" value="4"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="line_width_unit" value="MM"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="offset" value="0"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="offset_map_unit_scale" value="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="offset_unit" value="MM"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="ring_filter" value="0"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="trim_distance_end" value="0"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="trim_distance_end_map_unit_scale" value="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="trim_distance_end_unit" value="MM"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="trim_distance_start" value="0"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="trim_distance_start_map_unit_scale" value="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="trim_distance_start_unit" value="MM"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="tweak_dash_pattern_on_corners" value="0"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="use_custom_dash" value="0"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="width_map_unit_scale" value="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
          </Option>
          <prop k="align_dash_pattern" v="0"/>
          <prop k="capstyle" v="flat"/>
          <prop k="customdash" v="5;2"/>
          <prop k="customdash_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
          <prop k="customdash_unit" v="MM"/>
          <prop k="dash_pattern_offset" v="0"/>
          <prop k="dash_pattern_offset_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
          <prop k="dash_pattern_offset_unit" v="MM"/>
          <prop k="draw_inside_polygon" v="0"/>
          <prop k="joinstyle" v="round"/>
          <prop k="line_color" v="0,0,0,255"/>
          <prop k="line_style" v="solid"/>
          <prop k="line_width" v="4"/>
          <prop k="line_width_unit" v="MM"/>
          <prop k="offset" v="0"/>
          <prop k="offset_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
          <prop k="offset_unit" v="MM"/>
          <prop k="ring_filter" v="0"/>
          <prop k="trim_distance_end" v="0"/>
          <prop k="trim_distance_end_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
          <prop k="trim_distance_end_unit" v="MM"/>
          <prop k="trim_distance_start" v="0"/>
          <prop k="trim_distance_start_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
          <prop k="trim_distance_start_unit" v="MM"/>
          <prop k="tweak_dash_pattern_on_corners" v="0"/>
          <prop k="use_custom_dash" v="0"/>
          <prop k="width_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
          <data_defined_properties>
            <Option type="Map">
              <Option type="QString" name="name" value=""/>
              <Option name="properties"/>
              <Option type="QString" name="type" value="collection"/>
            </Option>
          </data_defined_properties>
        </layer>
        <layer enabled="1" locked="0" class="SimpleLine" pass="0">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option type="QString" name="align_dash_pattern" value="0"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="capstyle" value="flat"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="customdash" value="5;2"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="customdash_map_unit_scale" value="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="customdash_unit" value="MM"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="dash_pattern_offset" value="0"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="dash_pattern_offset_map_unit_scale" value="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="dash_pattern_offset_unit" value="MM"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="draw_inside_polygon" value="0"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="joinstyle" value="miter"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="line_color" value="255,255,255,255"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="line_style" value="solid"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="line_width" value="4"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="line_width_unit" value="MM"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="offset" value="0"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="offset_map_unit_scale" value="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="offset_unit" value="MM"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="ring_filter" value="0"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="trim_distance_end" value="0"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="trim_distance_end_map_unit_scale" value="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="trim_distance_end_unit" value="MM"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="trim_distance_start" value="0"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="trim_distance_start_map_unit_scale" value="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="trim_distance_start_unit" value="MM"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="tweak_dash_pattern_on_corners" value="0"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="use_custom_dash" value="0"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="width_map_unit_scale" value="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
          </Option>
          <prop k="align_dash_pattern" v="0"/>
          <prop k="capstyle" v="flat"/>
          <prop k="customdash" v="5;2"/>
          <prop k="customdash_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
          <prop k="customdash_unit" v="MM"/>
          <prop k="dash_pattern_offset" v="0"/>
          <prop k="dash_pattern_offset_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
          <prop k="dash_pattern_offset_unit" v="MM"/>
          <prop k="draw_inside_polygon" v="0"/>
          <prop k="joinstyle" v="miter"/>
          <prop k="line_color" v="255,255,255,255"/>
          <prop k="line_style" v="solid"/>
          <prop k="line_width" v="4"/>
          <prop k="line_width_unit" v="MM"/>
          <prop k="offset" v="0"/>
          <prop k="offset_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
          <prop k="offset_unit" v="MM"/>
          <prop k="ring_filter" v="0"/>
          <prop k="trim_distance_end" v="0"/>
          <prop k="trim_distance_end_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
          <prop k="trim_distance_end_unit" v="MM"/>
          <prop k="trim_distance_start" v="0"/>
          <prop k="trim_distance_start_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
          <prop k="trim_distance_start_unit" v="MM"/>
          <prop k="tweak_dash_pattern_on_corners" v="0"/>
          <prop k="use_custom_dash" v="0"/>
          <prop k="width_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
          <data_defined_properties>
            <Option type="Map">
              <Option type="QString" name="name" value=""/>
              <Option name="properties"/>
              <Option type="QString" name="type" value="collection"/>
            </Option>
          </data_defined_properties>
        </layer>
        <layer enabled="1" locked="0" class="MarkerLine" pass="0">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option type="QString" name="average_angle_length" value="4"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="average_angle_map_unit_scale" value="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="average_angle_unit" value="MM"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="interval" value="40"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="interval_map_unit_scale" value="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="interval_unit" value="MM"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="offset" value="0"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="offset_along_line" value="8"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="offset_along_line_map_unit_scale" value="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="offset_along_line_unit" value="MM"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="offset_map_unit_scale" value="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="offset_unit" value="MM"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="placement" value="interval"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="ring_filter" value="0"/>
            <Option type="QString" name="rotate" value="1"/>
          </Option>
          <prop k="average_angle_length" v="4"/>
          <prop k="average_angle_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
          <prop k="average_angle_unit" v="MM"/>
          <prop k="interval" v="40"/>
          <prop k="interval_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
          <prop k="interval_unit" v="MM"/>
          <prop k="offset" v="0"/>
          <prop k="offset_along_line" v="8"/>
          <prop k="offset_along_line_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
          <prop k="offset_along_line_unit" v="MM"/>
          <prop k="offset_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
          <prop k="offset_unit" v="MM"/>
          <prop k="placement" v="interval"/>
          <prop k="ring_filter" v="0"/>
          <prop k="rotate" v="1"/>
          <data_defined_properties>
            <Option type="Map">
              <Option type="QString" name="name" value=""/>
              <Option name="properties"/>
              <Option type="QString" name="type" value="collection"/>
            </Option>
          </data_defined_properties>
          <symbol type="marker" name="@0@2" clip_to_extent="1" alpha="1" force_rhr="0">
            <data_defined_properties>
              <Option type="Map">
                <Option type="QString" name="name" value=""/>
                <Option name="properties"/>
                <Option type="QString" name="type" value="collection"/>
              </Option>
            </data_defined_properties>
            <layer enabled="1" locked="0" class="SimpleMarker" pass="0">
              <Option type="Map">
                <Option type="QString" name="angle" value="90"/>
                <Option type="QString" name="cap_style" value="square"/>
                <Option type="QString" name="color" value="255,255,255,255"/>
                <Option type="QString" name="horizontal_anchor_point" value="1"/>
                <Option type="QString" name="joinstyle" value="bevel"/>
                <Option type="QString" name="name" value="arrow"/>
                <Option type="QString" name="offset" value="0,0"/>
                <Option type="QString" name="offset_map_unit_scale" value="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
                <Option type="QString" name="offset_unit" value="MM"/>
                <Option type="QString" name="outline_color" value="0,0,0,255"/>
                <Option type="QString" name="outline_style" value="solid"/>
                <Option type="QString" name="outline_width" value="0"/>
                <Option type="QString" name="outline_width_map_unit_scale" value="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
                <Option type="QString" name="outline_width_unit" value="MM"/>
                <Option type="QString" name="scale_method" value="diameter"/>
                <Option type="QString" name="size" value="4.4"/>
                <Option type="QString" name="size_map_unit_scale" value="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
                <Option type="QString" name="size_unit" value="MM"/>
                <Option type="QString" name="vertical_anchor_point" value="0"/>
              </Option>
              <prop k="angle" v="90"/>
              <prop k="cap_style" v="square"/>
              <prop k="color" v="255,255,255,255"/>
              <prop k="horizontal_anchor_point" v="1"/>
              <prop k="joinstyle" v="bevel"/>
              <prop k="name" v="arrow"/>
              <prop k="offset" v="0,0"/>
              <prop k="offset_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
              <prop k="offset_unit" v="MM"/>
              <prop k="outline_color" v="0,0,0,255"/>
              <prop k="outline_style" v="solid"/>
              <prop k="outline_width" v="0"/>
              <prop k="outline_width_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
              <prop k="outline_width_unit" v="MM"/>
              <prop k="scale_method" v="diameter"/>
              <prop k="size" v="4.4"/>
              <prop k="size_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
              <prop k="size_unit" v="MM"/>
              <prop k="vertical_anchor_point" v="0"/>
              <data_defined_properties>
                <Option type="Map">
                  <Option type="QString" name="name" value=""/>
                  <Option name="properties"/>
                  <Option type="QString" name="type" value="collection"/>
                </Option>
              </data_defined_properties>
            </layer>
          </symbol>
        </layer>
      </symbol>
    </symbols>
    <rotation/>
    <sizescale/>
  </renderer-v2>
  <blendMode>0</blendMode>
  <featureBlendMode>0</featureBlendMode>
  <layerGeometryType>1</layerGeometryType>
</qgis>
```

### Update 1

Download this [style](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vQUH3DVLaQf-QHQMrj5bUU9y2IWuPp6B/view?usp=sharing) for `inversed`, `not inversed` and `two-way` roads.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works! now I add a field to manage the rotation, but how can I manage the style with no arrow if the link is a two-way-street? Do I have to post another question?

Comment: @Ale No arrow means no rotation. It is not quite clear what you mean. Perhaps another question needs to be asked.

Comment: I have three possible situations: 1 one-way (arrow north direction) 2 one-way (arrow south direction) 3 two-way (no arrows). With this script I can manage 1-2 situations, maybe with a rule I can manage also 3

Comment: @Ale See update 1.